# When would I want to create more than one verticles (assuming I am using non-blocking db clients in a stateless microservice)?

Tags: microservices, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

Assuming

- I am building a stateless micro-service which exposes a few simple API endpoints (e.g., a read-through cache, save an entry to database),
- I am using the non-blocking database clients e.g., [mysql](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/tree/master/vertx-mysql-client) or [redis](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/) and
- I always want my microservices to speak to each other via HTTP (by placing EC2 instances behind a load balancer)

Questions

1. When will I want to use more than 1 standard verticles (i.e., write the whole microservice as a single verticle and deploy n instances of it (n = num of event-loop threads))?. Won't adding more verticles only add to serialization and context-switching costs?
2. Lets say I split the microservice into multiple standard verticles (for whatever reason). Wouldn't deploying n (n = num of event-loop threads) instances of each always give better performance than deploying a different ratio of instances. As each verticle is just a listener on an address and it will mean every event-loop thread can handle all kinds of messages and they are load balanced already.
3. When will I want to run my application in cluster mode? Based on docs, I get the feeling that cluster mode makes sense only when you have multiple verticles and that too when you have an actual use-case for clustering e.g., different EC2 instances handle requests for different users to help with data locality (say using ignite)

P.S., please help if even if you can answer one of the above questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I always want my microservices to speak to each other via HTTP (by placing EC2 instances behind a load balancer)

It doesn't make much sence to use Vertx if you already went for this overcomplicated approach.
Vertx is using Event Bus for in-cluster communication, eliminating the need for HTTP as well as LB in front.

Answers:

1. Why should it? If verticles are not talking to each other, where the serialization overhead should occur?
2. If your verticles are using non-blocking calls (and thus are multithreded), you won't see any difference between 1 or N instances on the same machine. Also if your verticle starts a (HTTP) server over a certain port, then the all instances will share that single server accross all thread (vertx is doing some magic reroutings here)
3. Cluster mode is the thing which I mentioned in the beginning. This is the proper way to distribute and scale you microservices.

Comment: We have invested significant monitoring/ops effort into our existing stack (EC2s behind ELB) and cost saving is the primary reason for us moving from nodejs to vertx (we have 5000+ EC2 servers handling peak http traffic).


When I start running my microservices in vertx cluster, does 1 verticle per microservice make sense? And they speak to each other only over event-bus (without http)

Comment: 1 verticle per microservice makes perfect sense. Event-bus == p2p over TCP, also the calls are simpler

Answer (score 1):

1. A verticle is a way to structure your code. So, you'd want verticle of another type probably when your main verticle grows too big. How big? That depends on your preferences. I try to keep them rather small, about 200 LOC at the most, to do one thing.
2. Not necessarily. Different verticles can perform very different tasks, at different paces. Having N instances of all of them is not necessarily bad, but rather redundant.
3. Probably never. Clustered mode was a thing before microservices. Using it adds another level of complexity (cluster manager, for example Hazelcast), and it also means you cannot be as polyglot.

Comment: Hi alexey-soshin
I have split my microservice code into multiple folders/files `dao/` `entity/` `route/` for code structuring.
And kept 1 standard verticle (15 line body) which creates db connections and starts the http server.

We chose this approach to keep code simple (no generated code - vertxgen, proxygen etc).

Do you see any future limitations (performance, complexity) with this approach?

Comment: It would be very hard to say, even if I could look at your code, which I can't. Would recommend to monitor your application and see that it utilizes all available resources, especially CPU cores.

Comment: Thank you. 
Performance wise, I could push the CPU of all cores to > 85% during load testing by deploying 8 of above standard verticles on an 8 core machine.